# How to get Topographical Position Index (Tpi) to fill to edges r spatialEco

Tags: topography

I am running TPI on an elevation raster for an island (England).
Depending what the window is for the TPI calculation, I seem to get no data at the coastline - if i use 250m it is fairly narrow

- if i use 1000m it becomes quite wide.
  Please is there a way to ensure the moving window or the output fills to the edges.
  Output pictures shown are at 1 pixel = 1 hectare.  Thank you.

tpi250 <- tpi(ELEVATION, win = "circle", scale=250, zero.correct = TRUE)
[image]

tpi1000 <- tpi(ELEVATION, win = "circle", scale=1000, zero.correct = TRUE)

[image]